# Django, link a model field with an admin model field with ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm trying to link a "normal" model field with an admin model field, for example I have a table "Post" and I want to add the admin username as a ForeignKey to the field "Author" of the table Post.

I mean :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date_posted')
    username = models.ForeignKey(admin.username, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Where admin.username refers the username of `auth_user` admin model

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [*referencing the user model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) says, you can make use of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to obtain a reference to the user model that is used. You can use the [**`to_field=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) to specify to what field of the model it should refer, so:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date_posted')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        to_field='username'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )
```

By specifying [**`editable=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable) it will not automatically show up in `ModelForm`s.

In views, you can then set the logged in user as author by specifing the author attribute. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
> referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
> references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
> `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `_name` suffix. You might want to
> consider renaming the <s>`username`</s> field to `author`.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to migrate : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'Blog_post' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: Blog_post.username_id contains a value 'null' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user.username.

Comment: @GuillaumeHouioux: this is because you did not set the `form.instance.username = ...` in this case (or if you rename the field to author `form.instance.author = ...`. Django does not by default add the logged in user, since the model layer in a model-view-modelview is request-*unaware*).

Comment: I solved that problem but now I got this when I add a post in db ; NOT NULL constraint failed: Blog_post.username_id

Comment: This is exactly the same problem. You did not specify a value for the `username`, so the database will reject this.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date_posted')
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth_user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def username(self): return self.user.username
```

Usage:

```
some_post = Post.objects.get(id='the_post_id')
print(some_post.username) # prints some_post.user.username
```

Comment: It doesn't work cause I can't use auth_user directly in my models even if I import the admin models